# Can not use indexed key(_id) as a sharding key in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am a newbie of mongodb,here is a simple case but got an error:

I want to use `_id` field (generated and indexed automatically) as a sharding key in mongodb, but got this error.

```
{
"proposedKey" : {
    "_id" : "hashed"
},
"curIndexes" : [
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "jackfruit.scenicspots"
    },
    {
        "v" : 1,
        "key" : {
            "geoLocation" : "2dsphere"
        },
        "name" : "geoLocation_2dsphere",
        "ns" : "jackfruit.scenicspots",
        "2dsphereIndexVersion" : 2
    }
],
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "please create an index that starts with the shard key before sharding."
```

}

the error message showed that I already have an Index named `_id_` on key `_id`, why the error still occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer from manual.

> MongoDB does not support creating new unique indexes in sharded collections and will not allow you to shard collections with unique indexes on fields other than the _id field.

And here is a solution:

from[Enforce Unique Keys for Sharded Collections](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/)